# Partial derivative - Am I correct?

Tags: calculus

I have the following question for an assignment:

[assignment question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alK6A.png)

According to my calculations the answer is:

$$
(2e^t\sin t + 6e^t\sin^4 t)e^t + (e^{2t} + 12e^{2t}\sin^3 t)\cos t
$$

I queried the lecturer who assured me that one of the options provided is correct, rather than my solution.

Am I missing something basic?

Comment: It's not clear if you are missing some basic stuff when you don't show your works, but I do get the same answer

Comment: You might be missing that after simplification your answer equals one of the listed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w = x^2y + 3x^2 y^4 = x^2(y+3y^4)\\
\frac {dw}{dt} = 2x(y+3y^4) \frac {dx}{dt} + x^2 (1 + 12y^3)\frac {dy}{dt}$

Now $x = e^t, y = \sin t$

And substitute

$\frac {dw}{dt} = 2e^t(\sin t+3\sin^4 t) e^t + e^{2t}(1+12\sin^3 t)\cos t$

and simplify

$\frac {dw}{dt} = e^{2t} (2\sin t + 6\sin^4 t +  \cos t + 12\sin^3 t\cos t)$

I agree with you none of the listed answers are correct.  I cannot see how you get an $e^t$ term (as every listed answer has).